# In biopython, how can i get the 100% identity aligment?

Tags: bioinformatics, biopython

I find the way to get the identity of hsp ,but no alignment.One alignment can have multiple hsp, that means the score(identity) of  hsp is no equal to alignment.
when i do blast in webpage, i always get scores and identities of alignments.
Is that any logical problem i made, who can explain this?

Comment: cross posted: https://www.biostars.org/p/118504/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web page gives you the identity of some HSP, not the full alignment. E.g. these two HSPs:

```
1203 bits(651)  0.0     730/769(95%)    1/769(0%)   Plus/Minus
  106 bits(57)  6e-19     70/76(92%)    2/76(2%)    Plus/Minus
```

Give this count:

```
Max     Total   Cover   eVal ident
1203    1309    100%    0.0  95%
```

So the web is simply adding the scores (1203 + 106 = 1309) and probably averaging the eval and the ident (730+30) / (769 + 76) = 0.9467 ~ 0.95. So this is how you mimic the web BLAST "joined" stats. For the record, these two HSP have a gap between them that web-BLAST didn't include in the stats.